# Light options for kiwiViewer

Tags: ipad, opengl-es, 3d, shader, vtk

Im trying to add light options to kiwiviewer for visualization of medical 3D Models, in my case a surface model of a head.
I cant find a starting point for hours becouse when I delete all glsl shaders I still get the console output "INFO: Compiling shaders:" without error and the View with the 3D Model displaying correctly

I would appreciate any help.
Manuel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At build time, each shader is encoded into a cpp file and compiled into the library named libvesShaders.a.  If you modify a shader, but do not recompile the library and relink the application, the app will continue to operate with the previous version of the shader.

If you want to avoid the recompile step, you could create a new shader file and add it to the xcode project so that the file is packaged with the app.  Then read the shader source from the file on the iOS filesystem at runtime.

You might want to try the [VES mailing list](http://public.kitware.com/cgi-bin/mailman/listinfo/ves) for VES and KiwiViewer questions in the future.